# XmlSlurper Doesn't Parse the Whole XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, groovy, xmlslurper

I'm trying to access parts of an XML string after it was processed with XmlSlurper (inside the WS Lite plugin in case that matters).  Here's a sample XML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse>
    <GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult>
      <BusinessObject REF="21cf6434ae" Name="Incident" ID="1518">
        <FieldList>
          <Field REF="f5b2ef7e04" Name="ID">
            93e5346ec110eee46ea095
          </Field>
          [tons more field entries]
        </FieldList>
      </BusinessObject>
    </GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult>
  </GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have the body node and if I try to access just the GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse node or the GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult node everything seems to be working fine.  However, if I try to go deeper into the XML to get to the BusinessObject node (or deeper) that's when things stop working.

For example, the following code:

```
def node = body.GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse[0].GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult[0]
```

returns a proper NodeChild object.  However, if I do the following:

```
def node = body.GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse[0].GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult[0].BusinessObject[0]
```

I get a NoChildren object.  It seems like the BusinessObject node (and all it's children) are not being parsed.  They exist as a string if I do the following:

```
body.GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse[0].GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult[0].text()
```

but they don't exist as parsed objects.

This is the first time I've had to deal with XMLs in Groovy so I might be doing something wrong, or maybe things are just broken.  Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is not valid xml. `</soap:Envelope>` is missing.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste mistake ... I've edited the question to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the XML string (it's a SOAP response) wasn't correctly formatted.  All the nodes that weren't getting parsed were actually using

```
&lt; and &gt;
```

instead of < and >.  However, XmlSlurper was actually converting the symbols to < and > but just not parsing them.  So looking at the XML after XmlSlurper did its thing made everything look correct.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
def xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
|              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
|              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
|  <GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse>
|   <GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult>
|      <BusinessObject REF="21cf6434ae" Name="Incident" ID="1518">
|        <FieldList>
|         <Field REF="f5b2ef7e04" Name="ID">93e5346ec110eee46ea095</Field>
|        </FieldList>
|      </BusinessObject>
|    </GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult>
|  </GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>""".stripMargin().stripIndent()

def parse = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

assert '93e5346ec110eee46ea095' == parse.Body
                                        .GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResponse
                                        .GetBusinessObjectByPublicIdResult
                                        .BusinessObject
                                        .FieldList
                                        .Field
                                        .text()
```

You do not have to deal with a NodeList until there is one. Here I see the only potential node list to be `FieldList`.